# Disable Authorization Schemes from Swagger when not in use

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

I am using the default swagger securityDefinitions/SecuritySchemes i.e

```
  petstore_auth:
    type: "oauth2"
    authorizationUrl: "http://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/dialog"
    flow: "implicit"
    scopes:
      write:pets: "modify pets in your account"
      read:pets: "read your pets"
  api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "api_key"
    in: "header"
```

If I login with one of the schemes, the second scheme doesn't get disabled which confuses the user in runtime. Is it possible to hide/disable all the other security schemes?

[image]

Comment: Explain more so that it will be understandable for us to solve.

Comment: @AshishKarn Lets say I want to configure client credentials and Authorization security schemes for OAuth2 , but at a time I will login into one of the scheme. Is it possible to hide/disable/remove the other schemes if one of the scheme is logged in?

Comment: I don't think that you can do on the same browser but you can create separate definition under securityDefinitions and use those on different API's and this will not be the right way.

Comment: @AshishKarn Could you please provide some example?

Comment: For example, creating two security definition as pet_auth: and store_auth: with the same definition and it's properties. And use that for two different APIs.